# Database deployment tool for windows

Tags: untagged

I need help with a MySQL database. We develop a big SaaS system on .net and we have 2 db servers:

- Local for developers, they make changes on this etc. This server is in other city where all team are.
- QA environment database server - this is used for QA of this solution.

We need to make auto sync between this two databases. When Cruise Control.NET deploy new version to QA environment we should get latest database structure from Local server to QA server.

Requirement is to have free software for doing this and it should be Windows.

Answer (score 0):

If free software is what you need, then might as well write your own pl/sql to handle majority of the work. I suggest setting up replication between your Dev and QA server. Here is a link on how to set up replication on MySQL server: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/replication-howto.html

If there are specific things you want to happen, such as data manipulation and such and need more than replication. Try setting up triggers Such as On Update or On Delete or On Insert, and do this or that. You can even invoke java cli from MySQL to do more than SQL operation. But if you are willing to spend a few hundred bucks, I recommend Navicat, which has a sync tool. And you can set up a customize sync to be executed.

Comment: Tanks for answer. The main problem that if we have Replication for QA we cant add data to this database (cause it's slave), we can only read from this.